# Ubuntu 12.04 Installed, monitor turns off after the BIOS screen

Tags: suspend, screen

After a little struggling, I managed to install Ubuntu 12.04. I can hear the computer running while the screen is off, and it turns off directly after the BIOS screen.

Specs:

- Case: Thermaltake V4 Mid Tower Case with 500W PSU - USB 3.0 - Transparent Window - 10x 5.25" & 3.5" Drive Bays - Front Speaker & HD Audio Inputs
- RAM: 4GB Memory, PC3-10600 (1333MHz) DDR3, 240-pin DIMM, Non-ECC, CL 9-9-9-24
- CPU: AMD A6-3500 Triple Core Fusion APU - Socket FM1 - 2.1GHz - 3MB L2 Cache - Integrated Radeon HD6530D Graphics - TDP 65W - Llano - Fan Included
- Mobo: ASRock A75M-HVS - AMD Socket FM1 - AMD A75 FCH Chipset - 2x DDR3-2400 - 1x PCIe x16, 1x PCIe x1 & 1x PCI - 6x SATA3 - 4x USB3.0 - D-Sub & HDMI - 5.1 Channel Audio - Gigabit LAN - Micro ATX
- SSD: Crucial M4 64GB SATA 6GB/s S- 2.5" - 500MB/s Read & 95MB/S Write - NAND Management (details on the partitioning of this drive below.
- HDD: Western Digital WD Caviar Blue 3.5" 1TB SATA 6.0Gb/s 7200RPM 32MB Hard Drive
- Monitor: HP LE2001wm 20" Widescreen LCD - 1600 x 900 Resolution - 250 cd/m2 - 1000:1 Contrast Ratio - 5 ms Response Time - DVI-D & VGA - Speakers

When installing Ubuntu I used the 64 GB SSD for the following partitions:

- 500MB `/boot` partition which I asked the bootloader to run from
- `/` 10GB
- swap 2GB
- `/home` partition with the remainder of the space on the disk.

Comment: Try loading BIOS defaults and try.

Comment: Not sure what you mean sorry.

Comment: You can get in the BIOS by pressing either Del, or F2.  Look for load setup defaults, load it, Save and exit.

Comment: The monitor simply goes back to sleep again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) for determining the disk space requirements for partitioning

Answer (score 2):

## nomodEset:

MavNix, I believe the reason you are still having issues is because you mistyped the necessary parameter 'nomodset'. It should be 'nomodeset', with an e (lower case). Thanks and hope you get it running.

Answer (score 0):

That may be a problem with your RADEON graphics card:

> AMD A6-3500 Triple Core Fusion APU - Socket FM1 - 2.1GHz - 3MB L2
>   Cache - Integrated Radeon HD6530D Graphics - TDP 65W - Llano - Fan
>   Included

When you boot the computer,hold Shift which will get you to the GRUB menu.Then E to edit the command line,use the keys to move to the line where is says `quiet splash` and add `nomodeset` . Then press F10 to boot.

Comment: I don't want to get this wrong, so add nomodset directly after quiet splash?

Comment: yes.it should be like quiet splash nomodeset

Comment: after doing that and hitting f10 it just powers down the monitor again. 

I'll list the full screen in case you/anyone can spot a problem

setprams 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae'

recordfail
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid -set=root d942fp0f-8b86-44fb-be42-41be51cfda2c
linux /vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae root=UUID=6babe0f1-81c0-445e-92f8-8ad0bb977525 ro  quiet splash nomodset $vt_handoff initrd /initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae

Comment: Sorry about the huge chunk of info, I can't figure out how to put the writing into new lines.

Comment: Check you system RAM.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Once I add in nomodset as you mentioned, how do I make it a permanent change? When I have managed to add in nomodset before or after quiet splash, it hasn't been there after I rebooted.

Comment: Still at a total loss as to how I can edit the grub etc.